# Calculating the integral of the absolute difference between two multivariate normal functions.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, numerical-methods

Suppose we wanted to calculate the integral of the absolute difference between two joint normal functions, essentially the L1 norm.  We have $\mathbf{\mu}_1$, $\mathbf{\mu}_2$, $\mathbf{\Sigma}_1$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma}_2$ as the means and co variance matrices of each respective distribution.  So $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(X_1|\mathbf{\mu}_1,\mathbf{\Sigma}_1)$ and $X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(X_2|\mathbf{\mu}_2,\mathbf{\Sigma}_2)$.  Is there an analytical way that anyone knows how to calculate,

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{\mu}_1,\mathbf{\Sigma}_1)-\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{\mu}_2,\mathbf{\Sigma}_2)|\text{d}\mathbf{Y}$.

I'm curious for cases Y is 1 dimensional, 2 dimensional or N dimensional.  I'm assuming that there isn't and am currently calculating such values numerically, but if anyone knows any way to do this nicely then any help is appreciated.

Comment: Now if you wanted the $L^2$ norm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a closed form solution.  Your question is reducible to the problem of finding the probability that an inhomogenous quadratic form in a gaussian  random vector is positive.  (The matrix of the form being $\Sigma_1^{-1}-\Sigma_2^{-1}$, etc.)

In particular, the inhomogeneous quadratic form is $Q(x)=\log (f_1(x)/f_2(x))$ where the $f_i$ are the 2 gaussian densities involved.  Your integral is $$\int \left|f_1(x)-f_2(x)\right|\,dx = \int_{Q(x)>0} (f_1(x)-f_2(x)) \,dx - \int_{Q(x)<0}( f_2(x)-f_1(x))\,dx.$$ Each of the 4 little integrals ($\int_{Q>0} f_1(x)dx$, etc) is of the sort I describe above.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  Could you elaborate on this point a bit for me?  I understand how from the normal  distributions $(Y-\mu_i)^T\Sigma_i^{-1}(Y-\mu_i)$ is in inhomogenous quadratic form, but I don't see how we can transform this integral into the same problem.  Are you saying that such a probability is equal to the integral I ask?

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: I see, this makes it clear.  Thank you very much!